# jqGrid: client side sort doesn't work with dates!

Tags: jqgrid

I have a date column in a [jqGrid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) with colOption for that column defined as:

```
{name:'LTD', index:'LTD', width:110, align:'right', sortable:true, sorttype:'date', formatoptions:{srcformat:'Ymd', newformat:'d/m/Y'}, formatter: 'date'},
```

The JSON data returned from the server has '20101231', etc. in the field, and it gets displayed properly (that is, it's displayed like '31/12/2010'). However, clicking in the column header to sort it, does nothing!

The only way I could get the sort working was to not change the srcformat (that is, accept the default of 'Y-m-d'). However, it doesn't work with any other custom format.

An additional issue is with the search on this column. No matter how I specify the value in search popup (with equal as operator), it doesn't find the record!!

```
jQuery : 1.4.4
jqGrid:  3.8.2
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

The format option where `srcformat` or `newformat` has format 'Ymd' is not supported by 'date'. If must be a string which contain separators between 'Y', 'm' and 'd'. So I strictly recommend you to change your server code to produce date in the ISO 8601 Date format 'Y-m-d'.

If you can not change the code of the server you will have to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to be able to display the date in the newformat:'d/m/Y'. The following parameters for the date column can you use instead of `formatoptions:{srcformat:'Ymd', newformat:'d/m/Y'}, formatter: 'date'`:

```
sorttype: 'date', datefmt:'d/m/Y',
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var y = Number(cellvalue.substring(0,4));
    var m = Number(cellvalue.substring(4,6));
    var d = Number(cellvalue.substring(6,8));
    return String(d)+'/'+String(m)+'/'+String(y);
}
```

You will be able to display and make local sort of the data, but for the searching of data you will have to use the source format "20101016" if you want to search for the date which will displayed as "16/10/2010". See small demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateSort.htm).

Comment: @Jack Dorsey: You don't commented my answer. Do you read it?One more thing which I mention: you don't use voting till now. Starting with reputation 15 you have the right to vote up answers and questions of other persons. Here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask will be described standard rules for voting up questions/answer.

Comment: I have the same problem and when I alert cellValue it shows something like: `1322550786997` I get date as not formatted from server. Do you have an idea what should I do?

Comment: @kamaci: You have another case as described in the question. In the question the date the source data as the string `'20101231'` need be displayed as `'31/12/2010'`. You have UNIX data format, but as Number or String it's not clear for me. It would be better if you posted separate question with full information needed to reproduce the problem: jqGrid definition and the JSON input data (or the test data in any other form).